# Candlestick chart not appearing correctly in ios using danielgindi/Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, candlestick-chart

```
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    let financialData = data

    for chartData in financialData{
            let dataEntry = CandleChartDataEntry(x: chartData.date, shadowH: chartData.High, shadowL: chartData.Low, open: chartData.Open, close: chartData.Close)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = CandleChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.axisDependency = .left
    chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    chartDataSet.increasingColor = UIColor.green
    chartDataSet.increasingFilled = false
    chartDataSet.decreasingColor = UIColor.red
    chartDataSet.decreasingFilled = true
    chartDataSet.barSpace = 0.25
    chartDataSet.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray
    chartDataSet.neutralColor = UIColor.blue

    let chartData = CandleChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartView.data = chartData

    let xaxis = chartView.xAxis
    xaxis.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
```

Below is the sample data set that is being received from server and the image showing the chart being displayed.
https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/gdax/btcusd/ohlc?periods=60

[ CloseTime, OpenPrice, HighPrice, LowPrice, ClosePrice, Volume ]

I need help in fixing the display of data as currently it doesn't resemble a candle stick chart in any way. Can someone please help me in what I am doing wrong here.

[CandleStick chart data being displayed in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTP7Y.png)

Comment: What framework are you using? That's an important bit of information if you want help. You should put that in the title, and/or make it a keyword in your question.

Comment: I am using this charts library - https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 1):

So just in case anyone is having the same problem, i was having issues with the candles too and i found a solution based on this post:
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2742

- Create a class for your chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter that supports your entries with your init.
- Once you have your results entries, i used the enumerated value for the x on the CandleChartDataEntry
- In the stringForValue method inside your class that inherits from IAxisValueFormatter work the way you want to present your string, in my case was dates.

First two points:

```
//Check nil results
if result != nil {

//Save to Holder for future use
self.historyData = result

// Set the formatter class for the chartView
self.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter       = dateFormatter(elementsForFormatter: self.historyData!)

//Create a new chart data entry
var chartEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()

//Loop results
result?.enumerated().forEach({ (i, element) in

    // I'm force unwrapping, but please take care of this don't do me...
    let newDataEntryValue = CandleChartDataEntry(x:Double(i),
                                                 shadowH: element["high"] as! Double,
                                                 shadowL: element["low"] as! Double,
                                                 open: element["open"] as! Double,
                                                 close: element["close"] as! Double)

    chartEntries.append(newDataEntryValue)
}) 


}
// Do rest of conf. for your chart....
```

Last point (class implementation):

```
class dateFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

var elements:Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>

init(elementsForFormatter:Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>) {
    self.elements = elementsForFormatter
}
 func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short

    //Get the date based on the value which is the index
    if let time = self.elements[Int(value)]["time"] as? Double {
        print(time)
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(time)))

        return dateString

    } else {
        return ""
    }


}
}
```

Hope this helps someone!